# Access a js file from java in a project with tomcat directory structure (java.io.FileNotFoundException)

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat

I should call a javascript function from java.

I use a ScriptManager:

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader("js/myjsfile.js"));
Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;   
Boolean val=(Boolean)inv.invokeFunction("check", value);
```

I obtain a java.io.FileNotFoundException.

My project uses the tomcat directory structure:

```
-java src
-WebContent
 index.jsp
 ->js-> myjsfile.js
 ->jsp
 ->WEB-INF
 ->META-INF
```

How could I access to js/myjsfile.js from a java file?

**EDIT**
I resolved with

```
 String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/js/myjsfile.js");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the absolute path to read the js file and The absolute path of "catalina.home" can be get from the System property.

Comment: but I need also the runtime appname, do I? how can I retrieve it?

Comment: If you can obtain the HttpServletRequest class,you can invoke the getContextPath method to get the runtime appname.

Comment: Or you can get web path using code like follow(Assume that the code fragment was involved in the file A.java):                                      String webPath = A.class.getResource("/").getPath();                                 webPath = webPath.substring(0,webPath.lastIndexOf("/WEB-INF/classes/"));

Comment: I resolved with String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/js/myjsfile.js");